# Sharing variables between differents DLL but in the same process/EXE

Tags: c#, dll, process

I declared a static  variable in DLLA and I would like to access from another DLLB

How can I share a variable between two DLL which are running in the same process?

The problem is: In the following code the localB variable cannot be retreived. How can I read variable B inside the Main method?

- DLLA

  ```
  namespace A
  {
  public class ProgramA
  {

  public static string variableA = "John";
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {

      b.Program.variableB = variableA;
  }
  ```
- DLLB

  ```
  namespace b
   {
   public class Program
    {
      public static string variableB;
      public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         string localB = variableB;
     }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If DLL2 has a reference to DLL1 you simply have to mark that variable (and the class that contains it) as `public`.

Comment: When I do that you said, the variable is read without running the DLL1. And I have to read it after running DLL1!

Comment: If you need to run something inside DLL1 **BEFORE** someone reads UserName then write a static constructor (you'll be sure it's invoked before the access of any static field of that class). Moreover, what do you mean with _running DLL1_?

Comment: The scenario is: DLL1 set a variable so first of all I have to run DLL1. Then running DLL2, the variable set in DLL1 must be read by DLL2.

Comment: please, I improved my question. Thanks.

Comment: In the updated  example is A that depends on B! Moreover note that you must invoke the Main method by yourself, it's not an entry-point. If

Answer (score 1):

In first DLL (First.DLL)

```
namespace MyGlobalVar
{
    public static class MyAppVars
    {
        public static string UserName;
    }
}
```

In second DLL (Second.DLL) reference First.DLL then use as:

```
using MyGlobalVar
....

MyAppVars.UserName = "John";
```

Comment: Why the variable can be read without initializing the first DLL?

Comment: Because the Class is declared as Static. So every public variable is also static and created/initialized automatically by the runtime at the first use of the class. No need to declare instance of this class with new. (The compiler will not let you create an instance). More info on static class here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: When the class is not static? How to read the variable from another class? I edited my initial question.

Comment: In your revised example is not possible to reach, from the outside of method Main the localB variable. It's a local variable internal to the Main method and will be destroyed immediately after the execution of the method's code. However variableB is declared as static so you can reach with the used syntax (provided you have the right references and using in place)

Comment: So, What can I reuse a global variable when a Main method is called?